# How to access home directory and auto create directory on install

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I want to create a directory with some config file on the installation process and user home directory. My questions are:

-> how to create this directory while installing

-> how to access home directory from c# code

Comment: Is this being done in C#.. please clarify what environment you are doing this for.

Comment: @DJKRAZE as I wrote this id done in c#. if I would do it in html i would ask how to access it from c#. tags describes environment

Comment: I ask because I gave a solution but someone marked down vote because they thought that you were doing this in metro

Comment: C#.. you have that tagged too..LOL good luck Fixus

Comment: @DJKRAZE thank you. good luck for you too. c# is language i'm using. metro and winrt is version of os that i'm building app for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have access to some special folders for your application.  You can save a file to the LocalFolder like this:

```
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("config.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "Text to write to file");
```

and then retrieve it:

```
file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("config.txt");
```

There's also a RemoteFolder for files you want available to the user if they use your application on another device.

This folder can be found by going to something like "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages" and then finding the folder for your app.

Comment: probably this is what I was looking for. I'll check this soon

Comment: will this work if I'll add your code and just run my app ? I've added this code but can't find the file :(

Comment: Just edited my code to make it clearer what to pass to FileIO.WriteTextAsync - the second parameter should be what you want to save.  Does that help?  I don't imagine it would save if you didn't pass it some text :o)

Comment: strange. i did the same but now works. Nvm, most important that it works. I have just one more question about this code. Is this a temp directory ? Can I assume that if I'll create a config file there it won't vanish ?

Comment: Data in that folder should be safe.  There's a TemporaryFolder for anything you don't need to keep around.  There's more details over here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241587.aspx